# Customize Android UI sign-up fields

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

We just started using AWS mobile hub and used Cognito for user sign in, with the default authentication UI. However, we have other fields that are required in our user pool, such as gender and date of birth, which is not reflected in the Sign-Up UI. This results in the fact that we are not able to log in, since we are not able to provide these attributes when signing up, as they are not part of the UI.

At the moment the sign up UI has username, password, given name, email address and phone number as the fields, even though only password, email and username are required in our user pool. How can we customize the fields shown to the user, including removing the non-required ones, as well as adding gender, date of birth etc?

We have spent hours googling this to no avail, so we really really hope someone can help us with this issue. We have found multiple ways to customize the css and look of the UI, but no way to actually alter the fields.

Thanks in advance.